# Unity3d crash after switching a scene containing a webcamtexture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two scene that i want to switch between them : Scene A and B 
Scene A is the default scene Scene B is the scene containing a 3d plane having the default texture as webcameTexture and this is it's script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Camera_panel_script : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
public string deviceName;
 WebCamTexture webCameraTexture;
private WebCamDevice[] devices;

// Use this for initialization

IEnumerator Start() {

    yield return Application.RequestUserAuthorization(UserAuthorization.WebCam | UserAuthorization.Microphone);
    if (Application.HasUserAuthorization(UserAuthorization.WebCam | UserAuthorization.Microphone)) {
        WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;

        foreach(WebCamDevice cam in devices)
        {
            if(cam.isFrontFacing )
            {    
                webCameraTexture  =    new WebCamTexture(cam.name);
                webCameraTexture.deviceName  = cam.name;
                //if (webCameraTexture != null && webCameraTexture.didUpdateThisFrame) {
                renderer.material.mainTexture = webCameraTexture;
                webCameraTexture.Play();
                //}

                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
    }
}
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Escape)) {
        if(webCameraTexture!=null && webCameraTexture.isPlaying){
            webCameraTexture.Stop();

        }
        if(!webCameraTexture.isPlaying)
        {
            DestroyObject(gameObject);
            Application.LoadLevel("Game");
        }

    }
}
```

}

when i try to switch to Scene A again my application crashes

```
if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Escape)) {
        if(webCameraTexture!=null && webCameraTexture.isPlaying){
            webCameraTexture.Stop();

        }
        if(!webCameraTexture.isPlaying)
        {
            DestroyObject(gameObject);
            Application.LoadLevel("Game");
        }

    }
```

How should i fix this problem ? i search out the unity forum and i couldn't have a proper solution for that

**Edit**

i changed my script to this :

```
 if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Escape)) {
    while (webCameraTexture!=null && webCameraTexture.isPlaying)
        {
            Debug.Log("is still playing");
            webCameraTexture.Stop();
            webCameraTexture=null;
            break;
        }
        Debug.Log("stoped playing");
        Application.LoadLevel("Game");
}
```

this work but the switching is too slow ,it took like a second to switch to scene A again

Comment: How do you change the scene to scene A? With that line Application.LoadLevel("Game")? Have you tried considering the option to properly dispose of the camera before switching to another scene? Also, can you show the code for scene A? There's obviously some exception that results in a loop and crashes your IDE.

Comment: yes Scene A is `Game` so `Application.LoadLevel("Game")` should  witch back to the Game scene ,what is the best method to dispose the camera before switching scene i did this :  if(webCameraTexture!=null && webCameraTexture.isPlaying){
            webCameraTexture.Stop();

        }
but is this the best method ? i don't know

Comment: in scene A there is a simple sprite with animator and a crossfade call every 20 sec or if Mousedown is triggered

Comment: Nothing else? Did you try to debug it to see what's exactly causing the crash?

Comment: the debugger just give me a log saying beginning of crash

Comment: You can post the stacktrace?

Comment: can you please check my update ?

Comment: You could make this process faster by marking the Camera_panel_script not destroyable on load and letting it finish all in the background with the new-loaded scene A already active.

Comment: what do you mean by : letting it finish all in the background with the new-loaded scene A already active.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed code (you shouldn't call Stop(), just call Pause and Change Scene:

```
if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Escape)) 
{
    while (webCameraTexture!=null && webCameraTexture.isPlaying)
    {
        Debug.Log("is still playing");
        webCameraTexture.Pause();
        webCameraTexture=null;
        break;
    }

    Debug.Log("stoped playing");
    Application.LoadLevel("Game");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to Stop the Webcamera and change the scene at the same time your game will crash.
In my case I was getting a memory violation.

> comm="UnityMain" reason="memory violation" sig=11'

Improving your solution a better code will be:

```
if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Escape)) 
{
    if (webCameraTexture != null && webCameraTexture.isPlaying)
    {
        Debug.Log("Camera is still playing");
        webCameraTexture.Pause();     

        while (webCameraTexture.isPlaying)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        Debug.Log("Camera stopped playing");
    }

    webCameraTexture = null;
    Application.LoadLevel("Game");
}
```

As you can see I'm only pausing the camera before change the scene.